# Invalid configuration object: webpack.server.js

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I am using this webpack file and am getting an error.

This is the webpack file:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
target: 'node',
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                presets: [
                    'react',
                    'stage-0',
                    ['env', { targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions']}}]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the error message:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a 
    configuration object that does not match the API schema.
    - configuration.context: The provided value 
    "C:\\Users\\}\\Desktop\\Node\\HelloWorld!\\new" contains exclamation mark 
    (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    -> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the `entry` option. If 
    `output.pathinfo` is set, the included pathinfo is shortened to this 
    directory.
    - configuration.output.path: The provided value 
    "C:\\Users\\}\\Desktop\\Node\\HelloWorld!\\new\\build" contains
    exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader 
     syntax.
    -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! new@1.0.0 dev:build:server: `webpack --config 
        webpack.server.js`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the new@1.0.0 dev:build:server script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
        additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01- 
08T16_11_48_069Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 15):

Had the same error. The problem seems to be in the path of your folder. It must not contain an exclamation mark(!).
Change folder 'HelloWorld!' to just 'HelloWorld' without the exclamation mark.

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: It helped me as well, my parent folder name contained exclamation mark(!) in the end. I removed that and it started bundling everything pretty well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just remove all   **!(exclamation marks)** from your Project's Directory path: like from **"C:\Users\}\Desktop\Node\HelloWorld!\new"** to this **"C:\Users\}\Desktop\Node\HelloWorld\new"**